# Android Studio Google Drive API Google Services Crash

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm currently trying to use the Google Drive API to read/write from my Google Drive, however every method I've tried results in either Google Play Services crashing, or just nothing happening (a result of using the Tasks API.) I don't really know what to do as Google hasn't been much help, and there's no error logs as it's not my app crashing, but Google Play Services crashing.

I'm currently using the following (the final of my attempts) after signing in with Google's Auth API:

```
GoogleSignInAccount account = resultOfGoogleSignIn;
DriveClient c = Drive.getDriveClient(getContext(), account);
DriveResourceClient rc = Drive.getDriveResourceClient(getContext(), account);

rc.createContents()
    .continueWithTask(
        new Continuation<DriveContents, Task<Void>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Void> then(@NonNull Task<DriveContents> task) throws Exception {
                Log.i(TAG, "Actually doing something, never reaches this though");
                return null;
            }
        })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Failed task, doesn't reach this either");
        }
    });
```

Not really sure what to do since there are no error logs to go off, and I've tried following Google's steps to getting Drive working through Google Auth API, but nothing's working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am having the same problem now.

Comment: Unfortunately not, sorry